# Remote and local xterm use different fonts

Tags: fontconfig

I am using WSL on Windows 10 with XMing X server. Everything works locally as desired, but when I launch a xterm from a remote location, it launches with a different font.

In my .Xdefaults I have the following lines:

```
`XTerm*faceName: Consolas
XTerm*faceSize: 12`
```

The remote xterm ignores them.

I added .config/fontconfig/fonts.conf file:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM 'fonts.dtd'>
<fontconfig>
<alias>
    <family>mono</family>
    <prefer><family>Consolas</family></prefer>
</alias>
<alias>
    <family>monospace</family>
    <prefer><family>Consolas</family></prefer>
</alias>
</fontconfig>
```

and rebuilt the font cache:

```
fc-cache -frv
```

and fc finds it:

```
~ >fc-match mono
consola.ttf: "Consolas" "Regular"
```

However, a remote xterm still does not pick up the correct font. Instead, it picks us a "default" font:

```
~ >fc-match 
DejaVuSans.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Book"
```

As far as I get, the remote xterm is compiled with freetype support:

```
~ >ldd /usr/bin/xterm
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x000014d0f86b1000)
        libXft.so.2 => /lib64/libXft.so.2 (0x000014d0f7fcb000)
        libfontconfig.so.1 => /lib64/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x000014d0f7d86000)
        libfreetype.so.6 => /lib64/libfreetype.so.6 (0x000014d0f7aca000)
```

So, I am at the end of my wits here. How do I change the default font that is returned with fc-match with no arguments?